# How to start in a specific directory after ssh login?

Tags: command-line, ssh, gnome-terminal

I have a shortcut as follows:

`Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'sshpass -p "mypass" ssh myuser@123.456.789.214'`

Question: how can I directly change the starting directory, eg to `/var/log`?
I tried `myuser@123.456.789.214:/var/log` but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

`-t "cd /var ; /bin/bash"` worked:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'sshpass -p "mypass" ssh myuser@123.456.789.214 -t "cd /var ; /bin/bash"'
```